# ASP.NET - Accessing Active Directory from code behind page

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I have made a web application, which reads/writes from/to Active Directory. In my web.config file there is

```
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

and

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

When I display

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

in some label, it shows `mydomain\myusername`, so I think impersonation works.

Now to the question. When I access the application on the server, where the IIS web server is running, everything works great. But when I access the web application from a remote PC, I get an exception (the label still shows "mydomain\myusername").

I have traced the problem down. In the code behind when I call

```
Forest currentForest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
```

the variable `currentForest` knows its `currentForest.Name`, `currentForest.RootDomain` or `currentForest.ForestMode`, but any call to `currentForest.Domains`, `currentForest.Sites` or `currentForest.GlobalCatalogs` results in

> System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryOperationException.

Now I'm lost and don't know what to debug further. The account I'm using is member of Enterprise Admins (multi-domain forest). I have tried it on two different servers with different IIS versions (IIS 7.5 and IIS 6.0) with no luck.

And the thrown exception isn't of much help:

> Exception Details: System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: An operations error occurred.
>   Source Error: An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>   DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072020): An operations error occurred.
>
> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) +557
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() +44
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() +42
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne) +98
>   System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ADSearcher.FindAll() +46
>   System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest.GetDomains() +543
>
> [ActiveDirectoryOperationException: An operations error occurred.]
>
> System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest.GetDomains() +512484
>   System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest.get_Domains() +44
>   myWebApp.ASPpage.Button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\myUser\documents\visual studio\Projects\MyWebApp\MyWebApp\ASPPage.aspx.cs:158
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +115
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +140
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981

**EDIT:** If it is not obvious, I want to use `currentForest.Domains` to search the whole forest (all domains) for a user given by UPN name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question in one of "Related questions" on this page. The answer was in this topic: [Why does DirectoryServicesCOMException occur querying Active Directory from a machine other than the web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760158/why-does-directoryservicescomexception-occur-querying-active-directory-from-a-ma?rq=1)

I found, that it was exactly my case. After reading the suggested Microsoft article, I learned, that impersonating works only for local resources on the IIS server. To access network resources (SQL, Active Directory), I have to set "Trust this computer for delegation" in the computer object in Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

It was because the IIS always authenticate therefore `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` shows`mydomain\myusername;` to verify that the impersonation works you could use:
`System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`, also the `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(true)` returns null when it is not impersonating.